# Transform an old flash animation to jquery animation

Tags: jquery, flash, jquery-animate

I have an old flash animation. You can watch it here : http://jsfiddle.net/RDjdk/

I would like to do this with jQuery... I'm sure it's possible now.

Do you know libraries or tuts which can help me ? Do you have some snippets which can help me ?

I take look on jRotate or CSS transition... but I don't know how to start.

The goal is

```
1) Create an aboslute element which hide the website
2) Rotate a big pictureand minimize the size
3) Rotate another smaller picture
4) When the animation is completed... hide the animation and display the website
```

Best regards,

Comment: Do take a look at CSS3 animations..

Comment: @ppsreejith, to add a link in a comment you should use `[link title](url)` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a tool like [Adobe Edge](http://html.adobe.com/edge/animate/) to do this kind of complex animations.

Comment: Does that run without any dependency in every browser ?

Comment: Look into polyfills if you need to support outdated browsers—or stay sane by allowing a little graceful degradation for something as non-essential to functionality as a logo animation.

Comment: Ok... I will try but i'm don't find resources for helping me on adobe edge.